# Certificate needed in both Apache web server and JBoss?

Tags: apache, https, jboss, ssl-certificate

I'm using httpd (Apache web server) in front of JBoss Application Server. All http requests are proxy passed to JBoss through a virtual host configured in Apache.

Now I want to use https instead of http. I have a certificate (self-signed for now). Do I need to use the certificate both in Apache and JBoss?

Comment: Only if for some reason you want/need to have encrypted communication between Apache and JBoss; otherwise just terminate SSL on Apache and use plain http between them..

Comment: Thanks for quick response 